# php simple image resize after upload

Tags: php, image, joomla, resize

I looked around for a while and found some very confusing and complicated stuff that I couldn't get to work.

I'm using chronoforms with joomla to make a form with an upload file script, and it uploads the image to the server with no problems, so far so good.

I need to take the uploaded image and resize it, better yet, is there a way to resize the image before uploading it to the server?

Thanks.

Comment: The example in the manual page on [`imagecopyresize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) should work for you.

Answer (score 15):

I use this easy 1 function that does it all

check it out :

http://www.nimrodstech.com/php-image-resize/

https://github.com/Nimrod007/PHP_image_resize

Answer (score 1):

I have used [PHPThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) for a few of my projects and found it easy to work with and has a small resource footprint. You can read the docs for more info, but is pretty easy:

```
$thumb = PhpThumbFactory::create('/path/to/source/image.png');

$thumb->resize(100, 100);

$thumb->save('/path/where/you/want/resized/image.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

[This example] is what you are looking for [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php).

```
<?php
// The file
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$percent = 0.5;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new dimensions
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$new_width = $width * $percent;
$new_height = $height * $percent;

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
?>
```

Comment: IMHO this is the wrong approach.  PHP has a great image processing library which will do what he needs **prior** to being transmitted.  This method, while technically correct, requires more bandwidth and puts more strain of the user agent.

Comment: Hmm i can see the point. Will try to improve this answer in my free time.

Comment: @FlyingGuy - The answer hasn't been edited so IDK what you're talking about but this IS the only native PHP image library (GD) and it DOES resample the image before being transmitted. In fact this answer has absolutely nothing to do with the client side at all.. So.. wtf are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Chronoforms (v4 here) does support this out of the box! *(I've seen random traces of this for older versions, too, down to 1.3.)*

I can just drag an `Image Resize` action (from under `Utilites`) to a desired form event (under `On Submit`).

NOTE: this is *not* for client-side resizing. For that you'd need a Javascript form uploader package, which can show a thumbnail before & during the upload. They are usually non-trivial to integrate. (And using those client-side thumbnails *also for uploading* along with the original image requires some even more advanced -- and accordingly more complicated -- stuff; I'd say it's rarely worth the extra pain, just bite the bullet and generate the thumbnail again on the server, and think about all those poor African kids, who have even tougher lifes than web developers. ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple resize library I created and can be found on [here on Github](https://github.com/Oberto/php-image-magician).

Will work with any framework.

An example of how to use the library:

```
// Include PHP Image Magician library
require_once('php_image_magician.php');

// Open JPG image
$magicianObj = new imageLib('racecar.jpg');

// Resize to best fit then crop (check out the other options)
$magicianObj -> resizeImage(100, 200, 'crop');

// Save resized image as a PNG (or jpg, bmp, etc)
$magicianObj -> saveImage('racecar_small.png');
```